# NGinx: set localhost/project to project git folder

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I am currently working on a small website in my free time. For development, I keep all git repositories in ~/git. Is it possible to configurate nginx so that if I go to localhost/A or localhost/B, it would use ~/git/A and ~/git/B respectively?

I am using fedora and tried with a single repo, but I keep getting 404:

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         /home/MartenBE/git/;
        index        index.html index.php;

        location /A/ {
            alias /home/MartenBE/git/A/;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think only following should work for you.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root         /home/MartenBE/git/;
    index        index.html index.php;
}
```

You don't need to add `location` module because you have already defined `root`. Now if you try **localhost/A/index.html**, Nginx will try to find it under **/home/MartenBE/git/A/index.html**.

What are the requests you are trying ?

Comment: I am just trying to get to the webpage by surfing to "localhost/A" in my webbrowser. The error log gives the following: 

> 2017/04/14 12:10:47 [error] 6046#0: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/A" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: ::1, server: _, request: "GET /A HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"

Comment: Got the issue, remove the default server block (the 2nd one)

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is good to seperate site configuration from main nginx conf file.
Do the following..

- Remove all `server` blocks from `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.
- create a file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/yourconf` with the following content.

  `server {
          listen       80;
          server_name  localhost;
          root         /home/MartenBE/git/;
          index        index.html index.php;
    }`
- Create a symlink to the config file inside `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/yourconf`.
- Remove `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` & reload the nginx config.

NOTE: if you are using ubuntu run `sudo service nginx reload`